# Call to a external function

Tags: solidity, import

I have two solidity files. Im trying to get access to one function that is in the second solidity file. I the first contract I import the file.

> import "./DateTime.sol";

How can now acced to one function of the imported file???

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
dateTime.getHour(1542798273);
```

My idea is to make what in Java it´s made like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Let us assume the contract name of the first contract (the contract you imported) eg : `contract1`

Now use `is` keyword to implement the functions of that contract like this
    contract myContract2 is contract1 { // Your code }

Now use the the functions directly just like the example below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract Factory {
    function getName() internal pure returns (string) {
        return "Your Name";
    }
}

contract Contract is Factory {
    string public Name;

    constructor () public {
        Name = getName();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Fine thats work. But now with the *is* atributte we apply inheritance no??

Comment: Yes we use `is` to derive from another contract. Derived contracts can access all non-private members including internal functions and state variables. Source: [https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#inheritance]